# How to obtain coefficient of determination (R^2) from a LASSO fit in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, statistics

In MATLAB we can perform cross-validated LASSO with

```
[w, FitInfo] = lasso(X, y, 'CV', 3);
```

and obtain the best weights with

```
w(:,FitInfo.IndexMinMSE)
```

How can we find the coefficient of determination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lasso.html) and the [coefficient of determination definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), I think the following code should do the job:

```
 optimal_weights = w(:,FitInfo.IndexMinMSE);
 SStot = var(y)*length(y);
 predicted_values = X*optimal_weights;
 SSres = sum( (y(:)-predicted_values(:)).^2 );
 R2 = 1 - SSres/SStot;
```

Note `SStot` could be computed with `sum()`, but I think using `var()` is a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer, by Yellows is correct, but you have to make sure to include the intercept term ==> 
Predicted_values = X*2(:,fitInfo.IndexMinMSE) + fitInfo.Intercept(fitInfo.IndexMinMSE)

Comment: it can be a comment

Comment: Okay @AniruddhaDas